# 503 Service Unavailable (Failed to connect to endpoint:

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vcenter

My Vsphere windows client threw this error while trying to connect to my vcenter. 
[image]

After following forum solutions, I ssh and check storage issues. There were two volumes which had maxed. 100%.

I cleared old logs and now my storage is healthy. 
[image]

When I reboot and restart services using
**service-control --start --all**
I get this error

**ERROR:root:Unable to start service vmware-cm**

[image]

I have combed many vmware/vcenter/vsphere forums without success.

Thank you.